# Automated login and password storage

Tags: php, browser-automation, password-storage

I wrote a simple PHP script to log into my mobile phone provider's website, check my balance, and send me an email if it's too low. I put the script on a distant server.

It seems that I have to store my password *as plaintext* in the script to be able to send it to the login page. However, I am a little bit reluctant to do this...

```
$user="foo";
$password="blah";
```

Is there a more secure way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* secure a system which is capable of logging you in automatically if someone has access to the source. Let's try to prove it.

> 1. `System Smart` is able to log you in without you having to do anything.
> 2. `Mr. Evil` has access to the source of `System Smart`.
> 3. `System Smart` knows *what to do* to log in as you. (From the first point.)
> 4. `Mr. Evil` knows what `Systems Smart` knows. (From the second point.)
> 5. `Mr. Evil` knows *what to do* to log in as you. (From the third and fourth points.)
>
> **Conclusion:** This scenario is **not** secure.

*This is proof by contradiction if you start with the hypothesis that the scenario is secure.*

**Update:** But if you want to just make it harder than plain-text then can use a symmetric key.

Comment: Yep, I know it cannot be secured. However, I wondered if there was better ideas than juste storing it as plaintext. Obfuscation is obviously not security, but it is still better than nothing.

Comment: Well, if I use a symmetric key, I'll have to store it in the file, so it's not that more efficient :/

Comment: True, but now no one will be able to *read* your password. Since the scenario will **never** be secure you can only make `Mr. Evil` which in turn will introduce inefficiency. You can even go nuts and take this a step further. Have you key and encrypted password on different servers and make them talk. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to obfuscate it, but ultimately none of those are much safer than plaintext if someone has access to the file - since you also need to decode it there to be able to log in on the provider's site.

Answer (score 1):

The script has the capability to log you in to your provider unattended.

This means that anyone who controls the script will also have this capability, usable by running the script.

Nothing you can do will prevent this.  The only solution is to either live with the potential compromise of your password, or to only place the script on a server you control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go overboard on it you could set it up in such a way that your password is stored in a mysql database encrypted using `aes_encrpyt` and then you create another script on another server that makes calls to the server with your password requesting the password by providing the salt for use with the `aes_decrypt` function.